# Regex to switch words?

Tags: regex, notepad++, powergrep

I have long list of two string in every row, numerical string and alphanumerical string (that are of different length in every raw), that I want to change (switch) position:

```
010110,file_1.txt
0120100,file_11.txt
```

To have this:

```
file_1.txt,010110
file_11.txt,0120100
```

Second string also include dots and underscores, as in example above.
I tried regex that I used before for similar task but it doesn't work, I tried in Notepad++ and Powergrep.

```
([^_]*),(.*)
```

Replace with:

```
\2_\1
```

Tried that regex (with variations) but didn't have result.

Comment: Why is there an underscore in your regex and replace strings?

Answer (score 5):

I'd do:

- Find what: `^([^,]+),(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$2,$1`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Use a reluctant quantifier `*?`:

```
Find: ^(.*?),(.*)
Repl: $2,$1
```

`.*?` matches as little as possible.

Comment: The second string doesn't appear to have commas in, so this shouldn't make any difference.